# Why does the double conversion of some integers (to float and back to int) not remain equal to its original number, yet some do?

Tags: c, integer, hex

I have two integer variables:

`int i1 = 0xdeadbeef` and `int i2 = 0xffffbeef`.

(`11011110101011011011111011101111 or 37359285591` and `111111111111111110111110111011111 or 4294950639` respectively).

---

`(int) (float) i1 == i1` evaluates as false, yet `(int) (float) i2 == i2` evaluates as true.

Why is this? In this system, both `ints` and `floats` are stored in 4 bytes.

Comment: None of those hex constants will fit inside a 32 bit `int`, because it's a signed type with 31 value bits only.

Comment: @tadman It's an exam question, not my own code. I did get some warnings when I put those statements through the compiler, and now I'm just wondering why the two answers are different.

Comment: This exam is just plain broken then. `int` is typically constrained to +/-2.1e9 and anything outside of those bounds is undefined behaviour. If these were `unsigned int` or `uint32_t`, then the values are valid, but you still have the problem with `float`.

Comment: @tadman Interesting. So why are the results different if they are both UB? Why does deadbeef just happens to work and the exam question is flawed?

Comment: That value has the first bit set, so it's invalid. Anything > `0x7FFFFFFF` is out of range. You can always fluke it out and have the IEEE rounding match the initial value.

Comment: @tadman "int is typically constrained to +/-2.1e9 and anything outside of those bounds is undefined behaviour" --> `int i1 = 0xdeadbeef` is not UB.  Conversion "... result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `float` has far less precision than `int`, it can't store all possible `int` values without them suffering some damage. Sometimes this damage just rounds your value, sometimes your rounded value matches precisely.

A [32-bit `float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) can only store 24 "significand bits", or numerical data. Other bits are reserved for things like exponent, NaN flagging, Infinity and so on, where that eats into the remaining storage space.

A `double` does have the required precision as it's usually a 64-bit representation that can store 53 bits of numerical data data.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of conversions going on.

`int i1 = 0xdeadbeef; int i2 = 0xffffbeef` incur *implementation defined* conversions as the constants are out of `int` range.  Here, they are "wrapped".

`i2` is a small value (15 significant bits) exactly representable as a `float`.

`i1` is not.  `i1` has 30 significant bits, 6 more than the 24 of `float`.  Those lower 6 are not 0, so `(float) i1` results is a *rounded* value.

```
int main() {
  int i1 = 0xdeadbeef;
  int i2 = 0xffffbeef;
  printf("%d\n", (int) (float) i1 == i1);
  printf("%d\n", (int) (float) i2 == i2);
  printf("%u %10d %17f %10d\n", 0xdeadbeef, i1, (float) i1, (int) (float) i1);
  printf("%u %10d %17f %10d\n", 0xffffbeef, i2, (float) i2, (int) (float) i2);
}
```

Output

```
0
1
3735928559 -559038737 -559038720.000000 -559038720
4294950639     -16657     -16657.000000     -16657
```

Answer (score 0):

C implementations commonly use a 32-bit `int`, and `0xdeadbeef` does not fit in 32 bits (one sign bit and 32 value bits). Initializing `i1` with `0xdeadbeef` results in a conversion to `int`. This conversion is implementation-defined. GCC, for example, defines it to wrap modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, and this is not uncommon.

So `int i1 = 0xdeadbeef;` initializes `i1` to deadbeef<sub>16</sub> − 2<sup>32</sup> = 3735928559 − 2<sup>32</sup> = −559038737 = −21524111<sub>16</sub>. As you can see from the 8 hexadecimal digits in “−21524111,” this number spans 30 bits from its leading 1 bit to its trailing 1 bit, inclusive (32 bits in 8 digits, but the first two are zeros). The format commonly used for `float`, IEEE-754 binary32, has only 24 bits in its significand. Any number spanning more than 24 bits in its significant bits does not fit in the format and will be rounded when converted to this `float` format. So `i1 != (int) (float) i1`.

In contrast, `int i12 = 0xffffbeef;` initializes `i2` to ffffbeef<sub>16</sub> − 2<sup>32</sup> = 4294950639 − 2<sup>32</sup> = −16657 = −4111<sub>16</sub>. This spans 15 bits (16 bits in 4 digits, but the first one is a zero). So it fits in the 24 bits of a `float` significand, and its value does not change when converted to `float`. So `i2 == (int) (float) i2`.